# OpenShift free plan shows 1 gear in use but no application installed

Tags: cloud, openshift, redhat, paas, gears

I'm subscribed to OpenShift free plan. The command line and the web interface are telling me that I have 1 of 3 gears in use but I don't have any applications installed. How is that possible?

rhc account gives:

Gears Used:         1

Gears Allowed:      3

Domains Allowed:    1

Allowed Gear Sizes: small

rhc apps gives:

No applications. Use '`rhc create-app`'.

So gears used should be 0.
How can I free up the gears?

Comment: encountered similar issue today. Confused by this undexpected behaviour. Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: it was quickly solved by the [OpenShift support](https://developers.openshift.com/contact.html). I can't say what the mistake was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should contact [Openshift support](https://developers.openshift.com/en/contact.html) and include your account details, i.e., username, application url, as stackoverflow is not a good channel for posting your private data.